# Git: one git user to control the repos of multiple physical users

Tags: git, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi, which I use as a Git server. There are multiple physical users accessing it and currently each of these users has their own login on the server. In other words, the users John and Doe can login to the server with SSH by running `ssh john@server.com` or `doe@server.com`.

The physical users have private Git repositories, which no other user is able to access. E.g. John's repos are located in `/home/john/repos` and Doe's repos are located in `/home/doe/repos` on the server.

What I want is only one user called `git`, which controls all users' repos. E.g, instead of John having the remote `john@server.com:repos/project.git`, he would use `git@server.com:john/project.git`. Similarly, Doe would push to `git@server.com:doe/some_other_project.git`

How can this be achieved while making sure that people cannot access each other's repos? The server is accessed via SSH.

Comment: Your current scenario uses Unix built-in facilities to isolate users, which you do not want to use.   This mean you need to find similar functionality to isolate users and add that code to what you have now.  This might be more complex than you expect.   What is the reason you do not want unix users logins?

Comment: The main reason for this setup is that I want to see how do to it in order to learn more about Git and UNIX. E.g. Github and Bitbucket use this approach so I just wanted to understand how this actually works and if it seems nice, I thought I could use it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set up someting like [gitlab](http://gitlab.org), which provides a web interface, various sorts of access control, and all sorts of other bells and whistles.

If you really want to roll your own:

Start with [directions in the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for setting up your server to permit access to a shared user over ssh.

Those instructions will get you a shared `git` account to which everyone has access, and would let anyone push to/pull from any repository.  We can implement a simple authorization layer that will restrict users to repositories in particular directories.

Start with a small wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh

repo_prefix=$1

eval set -- $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
case "$1" in
    (git-receive-pack|git-upload-pack|git-upload-archive)

        # prevent attempts at using dir/../path to escape
        # repository directory
        case "$2" in
            (*..*) echo "Invalid repository name." >&2
                   exit 1
                   ;;
        esac

        repo_path="$repo_prefix/$2"
        eval exec $1 $repo_path
        ;;

    (*) echo "Unsupported command" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

This will prepend a prefix path, provided as a command line argument, to all repository paths.  Now, we need to arrange for this wrapper to intercept git operations.

To use this, you will need to modify the public keys you add to the `git` user's `authorized_keys` file.  If you followed the instructions in the Git book, the `authorized_keys` file will have one or more public keys in it, like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA...== some comment
```

For each public key, you will need to add a configuration option that will cause the wrapper script to be called in place of the original command.  From the `sshd` man page:

> Each line of the file contains one key (empty lines and lines starting
>   with a ‘#’ are ignored as comments).  Protocol 1 public keys consist
>   of the following space-separated fields: options, bits, exponent,
>   modulus, comment.  Protocol 2 public key consist of: options, keytype,
>   base64-encoded key, comment.  The options field is optional...

And slightly further down:

> The following option specifications are supported (note that option
>   keywords are case-insensitive): [...]
>
> **command="command"**
>
> Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for
>   authentication.  The command supplied by the user (if any) is
>   ignored...The command originally supplied by the client is available
>   in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.

With that in mind, we modify our `authorized_keys` file to look something like this:

```
command="/usr/bin/git-wrapper.sh username" ssh-rsa AAAA...===
```

This means that when someone connects with the corresponding private key, `sshd` will run `git-wrapper.sh username`, causing our `git-wrapper.sh` script to prepend repository paths with the string `username`, ensuring that `git` will only see repositories in the given directory.  More specifically, when you run:

```
git push origin master
```

And assuming that `origin` points to `project.git` on the git server, then`git` will attempt to run on the remote server the command:

```
git-receive-pack project.git
```

Our wrapper script will intercept that, and transform it into:

```
git-receive-pack $1/project.git
```

So for example,  if our git `git` user home directory has no repositories:

```
git$ ls
```

And our `authorized_keys` file looks like this:

```
git$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
command="/usr/bin/git-wrapper.sh alice" ssh-rsa ... alice@example.com
command="/usr/bin/git-wrapper.sh bob" ssh-rsa ... bob@example.com
```

Then if `alice` does this:

```
alice$ git remote add origin git@mygitserver:project.git
git push origin master
```

She will see:

```
fatal: 'alice/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If we create the target repository:

```
git$ mkdir alice
git$ git init --bare alice/project.git
```

Then she can push:

```
alice$ git push origin master
[...]
To git@mygitserver:project.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

But if bob were try to clone that repository:

```
bob$ git clone git@mygitserver:project.git
```

It would fail:

```
fatal: 'bob/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Even if he tried something sneaky:

```
bob$ git clone git@mygitserver:../alice/project.git
Invalid repository name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

And that, in a somewhat verbose nutshell, is how you can access authorization for your git repository server.  Note that this was all done *for demonstration purposes only*; you would want a substantially more robust script in a production environment.