# Limit Read and Write Access to branches of a plain git repository based on user name

Tags: git

We are building an assessment process and want to limit the read and write access to specific branches for special users.

there are "normal" users that have read and write access to everything (these users will rate the answers) and there will be a given number of assessment users that should only have read access to master and read/write access to branches that contain their names (e.g. `assessment-john.doe`). Our assessment center will have a list with 500 users and passwords and will give each candidate a set of credentials from this list.

Short version: I'd like to configure git, that:

- Normal Users (e.g. `tobi`, `chris`) have:

  - read & write access to master
  - (ideally only) read access to branches starting with `assessment-`
- Assessment Users (e.g. `assessment-1`, `assessment-2`) have:

  - read access to master
  - read/write access to branches that have the same
    name as the user (e.g. `assessment-1`)
  - no access to other branches.

We want to use plain git (and ssh) without any version control gui server like gitlab or github as the task doesnt require this.

**EDIT**: To make it clear: Read control is way more important that write control. (except for master).

Comment: The task *does* require some sort of application to manage the permissions, because `git` by itself doesn't know anything about "users" or "access control".  A tool like Gitlab would completely solve your problem, and you don't even need to interact with the web ui if you don't like it other than using it to manage ssh keys.

Comment: But if you want to develop your own solution, a long time ago I wrote answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28402532/147356) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248062/147356) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454688/147356) that address similar questions.

Comment: we use gitlab enterprise in our company and I think those branch protection stuff is part of the enterprise functionality. but running a few hundred assessment candidates through our enterprise gitlab requires a lot of user licenses for the enterprise server. and I also don't want to setup ssh keys. I want to keep it as easy as possible for the users, but the code should not be public as if one publishes its solution others could copy it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot meet those requirements with built-in functionality of git.  Access control is left to the hosting environment.

You could fake some level of write permission (by using signed commits and hooks to reject pushes that violate the authorization rules), but probably not exactly what you're asking for; and the limited read permission is right out; you'd basically have to use separate repos.

You can write your own server to perform access control, or you can use an existing one; but your characterization of existing host software (implying that its main function is to provide a gui) is mistaken; and your assertion that your task doesn't require one is incorrect in light of access control being part of the task.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done now:

- clone a central repository
- strip any branches except master
- rename master with the branch name for the user
- copy some hooks in the repository
- give the correct user read access to the repository
- add the user to a group that is allowed to run a specific script via sudo as another user
- write a hook that pushes the branch to the central repository on a push of the user to its repository